# Facebook iOS SDK - Xcode 8 Swift 3 Doesn't work

Tags: ios, fbsdk, swift3, xcode8, ios10

At first, I've tried compiling my application, and it succeeded, but it crashed when it used Facebook methods.
Then, I deleted the frameworks and reinstalled them, but now it doesn't compiling.
The error:

> No such module 'FBSDKCoreKit'

Does it because of the Swift 3 syntax? What can I do in order to fix it?
When it does compile, it just crashes at the first time it uses those methods...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do the following things and you can import any swift file from "Pods"

1. Clean your project
2. Make sure that all your "Pods" > "Build Settings" > "Build Active Architecture Only" is set to "NO".
3. Don't run, just build your project.
4. Now, import any file from "Pods" to any swift file

This will solve your `import module` problem.

Comment: But I don't use pods for FBSDK

Comment: Well, I did it and it works. But, I still have a problem that I can't use FBSDK methods.

Comment: Well, Facebook wasn't the trigger for the crashes. But you helped a lot with your solution, thanks!

Comment: It's happening again...
ld: framework not found FBSDKCoreKit
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)